# Cannot connect to external servers in Minecraft-PE full version

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My internet connection, IP address, and port are ok and correct, but I can't connect to any server, it says cannot connect and or disconnected from server. My Minecraft is the full version and  is v0.7.6 alpha. I've been asking my friends, searching YouTube and Google for solutions, but its still not working. Do you know a possible solution? I have a pocket wifi and a Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

Comment: Are you sure they are Minecraft PE servers and not normal Minecraft servers?  What error message do you get?  Have you tried on a normal residential wifi?

Comment: Is pocket wifi still counted as residential wifi?

Comment: I havent, but my badass friend tried it and it worked

Comment: Make sure that you have full bars of wifi or it might not work.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that you are using Pocket Wifi. If you are using 3G or 4G, this may be the problem. You see, carriers all around the world block many game ports and therefore do not let you join any servers. I haven't work a way around it but soon I might

Source: I tried joining my own server when I was using 3G

Comment: Wrong! Sorry but it is wrong, "I havent, but my badass friend tried it and it worked". Sorry for 1 year delay :P

Comment: @ardaozkal We are both correct. Some carriers block game ports. Clearly your 'badass friend' has a carrier that doesn't.

Comment: Not mine, that was a quote from the op.